# How to properly create/find and use sounds realistically in a convincing way in Blender?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, software, recommendations

I started a short film recently. Everything is going fine except for the sound fx. The biggest problem I am having is finding sounds. I don't really know of any resources out there that have good quality sound for free. I have used [Freesound.org](http://www.freesound.org/), but find them really hard to implement into events in my film, and very hard to find the correct sound. I know, I could just make my own sounds, but only have a headphone mic and have little experience in editing sounds and doing foley. I guess what I'm trying to ask is how do you do your sound effects for your short films/animations.Do you use online resources or do you record your own sounds, and if so what editing software do you use. Do you add the sounds before rendering or in post production? I'm trying the achieve something as intricate as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TG3Y-eCste4&list=FLX9eNIySc7hWRJ8B6vVXTBA&index=3). Notice all the little sounds of key typing, the sounds of the atmosphere, computers, and movement of elements. I have no idea how to even approach something like that. I asked this in the blender section but some users said I would have better luck asking in the sound design section. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why not just find someone passionate about sound and collaborate? Just as there is no magic bullet for creating visuals like those you link to in the video, neither is there a shortcut to creating intricate, effective sound design. Let me know if you want to go that route - I work with talented sound students who would love to work on that sort of material.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are realising is that creating sound for film is an intricate process that should be considered from the early stages of the film production. And it's great that you are!

You can use library sounds for a lot of things but when your getting into more detail with the little sounds like keyboard typing and movement of elements it's best to create these yourself. It's called Foley art. I find its much quicker to record yourself acting out the footsteps that are roughly synchronised with the on screen acting than to get library sound and spend ages cutting each step up and syncing them with the actors movements.

Your best bet is to find an aspiring sound designer who would take your film, once picture locked, and create all the fx, ambiences and mix. Just check out your local filmmakers/film crew/sound design Facebook page or other local crew/production forums and post an add for a sound designer/foley artist. Or you could just have fun doing it yourself :)

Answer (score -2):

I use bit of every technique : sampling/resampling/recording/mangling records/synthesis/resynthesis...

Any result that seems right and accurate !